UnityAR Object moves with camera without updates
I'm working on a Unity AR application (version 2021.3.22f1) and I'm spawning objects within the app to the location of a QR code. Currently, I'm encountering an issue where my GameObject moves with the phone's movement, despite being anchored and having its updates suppressed. I once encountered a similar error where the AR Camera's transform wasn't reset to the origin (0, 0, 0), which might be related to the current issue.
Object when spawned
Object without updates after camera movement
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;

public class TrackingTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ARTrackedImageManager manager;
    private ARTrackedImage trackedImage = null;
    private GameObject instantiatedScene;
    bool tracking = false;
    public Button refreshButton;
    private AssetBundle materialsBundle;
    private AssetBundle assetsBundle;
    private List<GameObject> spawnedPrefabs = new List<GameObject>();
    private ARAnchorManager anchorManager;
    private ARAnchor anchor;

    private void Awake()
    {
        manager = GetComponent<ARTrackedImageManager>();
        anchorManager = FindObjectOfType<ARAnchorManager>();

        if (anchorManager == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("ARAnchorManager not found. Make sure it's added to the AR Session Origin.");
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        MutableImageLibrary.OnlibraryComplete += OnlibraryComplete;
        if (refreshButton != null)
        {
            refreshButton.onClick.AddListener(OnRefreshButtonClicked);
        }
    }

    private void OnlibraryComplete()
    {
        //var arSessionOrigin = FindObjectOfType<ARSessionOrigin>();
        //arSessionOrigin.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        //arSessionOrigin.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

        Debug.Log("start tracking");

        manager = FindObjectOfType<ARTrackedImageManager>();
        manager.requestedMaxNumberOfMovingImages = 100;
        manager.trackedImagesChanged -= OnTrackedImagesChanged;
        manager.trackedImagesChanged += OnTrackedImagesChanged;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        MutableImageLibrary.OnlibraryComplete -= OnlibraryComplete;
        manager.trackedImagesChanged -= OnTrackedImagesChanged;
    }

    private void OnTrackedImagesChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        foreach (var image in eventArgs.added)
        {
            OpenScene(image);
            trackedImage = image;
        }

        foreach (var image in eventArgs.updated)
        {
            if (tracking)
            {
                if (instantiatedScene != null)
                {
                    UpdateScene(image);
                    tracking = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (image.trackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
                    {
                        OpenScene(image);
                        trackedImage = image;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var image in eventArgs.removed)
        {
            RemoveScene(image);
        }
    }

    private void OpenScene(ARTrackedImage image)
    {
        string imageName = image.referenceImage.name;
        Debug.Log($"Open Scene: {imageName}");

        string saveFolder = Config.instance.GetLocalPhysicsBundlesFolder() + "/" + imageName + "/";
        string assetsPath = saveFolder + "assets";
        string materialsPath = saveFolder + "materials";
        
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(materialsPath) && File.Exists(assetsPath))
            {

                // Load the materials asset bundle
                materialsBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(materialsPath);
                if (materialsBundle == null)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Failed to load materials bundle.");
                    return;
                }

                // Load the assets asset bundle
                assetsBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(assetsPath);
                if (assetsBundle == null)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Failed to load assets bundle.");
                    return;
                }

                // Call the method to spawn the scene from the assets bundle
                Debug.Log("Spawning Scene");

                // Load the main scene GameObject from the asset bundle
                GameObject scenePrefab = assetsBundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>(imageName);
                if (scenePrefab != null)
                {
                    // Instantiate the prefab in the current scene
                    var imageTransform = image.transform;
                    instantiatedScene = Instantiate(scenePrefab, imageTransform.position, imageTransform.rotation);
                    // Trying to anchor the Object
                    anchor = anchorManager.AddAnchor(new Pose(imageTransform.position, imageTransform.rotation));
                    instantiatedScene.name = imageName;
                    
                    spawnedPrefabs.Add(instantiatedScene);
                    Debug.Log("Name: " + instantiatedScene.name);
                    tracking = true;
                    
                    if (anchor!= null)
                    {
                        instantiatedScene.transform.SetParent(anchor.transform, false);
                        instantiatedScene.transform.localRotation = imageTransform.rotation;
                        instantiatedScene.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero; 
                        Debug.Log("Object anchored successfully.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("Failed to create anchor.");
                        // Destroy object if anchor creation fails
                        Destroy(instantiatedScene); 
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Failed to load the scene prefab from the assets bundle.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Materials or assets file does not exist.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    private void RemoveScene(ARTrackedImage image)
    {
        if (image == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Remove Scene got called without an image");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log($"Remove Scene: {image.referenceImage.name}");
            string imageName = image.referenceImage.name;
            if (instantiatedScene != null)
            {
                Destroy(instantiatedScene);
                UnloadAssetBundles();
                Debug.Log($"Scene removed: {imageName}");
            }
            else
            {
                if (GameObject.Find(imageName) != null)
                {
                    instantiatedScene = GameObject.Find(imageName);
                    Destroy(instantiatedScene);
                    UnloadAssetBundles();
                    Debug.Log($"Scene removed: {imageName}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError($"Scene not found: {imageName}");
                }
            }

            trackedImage = null;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateScene(ARTrackedImage image)
    {
        Debug.Log("Update Scene");
        // Ensure the scene object is not null
        if (instantiatedScene != null)
        {
            // Position the scene at the tracked image's location
            var transform1 = image.transform;
            
            if (image.trackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
            {
                // Only update when the image is actively tracked
                instantiatedScene.transform.position = transform1.position;
                instantiatedScene.transform.rotation = transform1.rotation;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Instantiated scene object is null. Cannot relocate.");
        }
    }


    private void OnRefreshButtonClicked()
    {
        RemoveScene(trackedImage);
        tracking = true;
    }

    private void UnloadAssetBundles()
    {
        // Unload the materials and assets bundles here
        if (materialsBundle != null)
        {
            materialsBundle.Unload(true); 
            materialsBundle = null; 
        }

        if (assetsBundle != null)
        {
            assetsBundle.Unload(true); 
            assetsBundle = null;
        }
    }
}

I tried to reset camera position, anchor the object, checking if the object was somehow attached to the AR camera (AR camera doesn't have children), disabled all physics within the scene and disabled all tracking update.
I expected that my object would not move at all even when the camera gets moved, but it still moved with the camera.
